# Insert new data into a table whether it is existed or not

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am learning SQL and have a small question. I created this table with 2 columns

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employer(empid TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE, building TEXT);`

Now I want to save values `(emp123,b88)` into the table. But I dont know whether this `empid` existed or not.

If it is existed (for example `(emp123,b30)`), then it should be replaced with `(emp123,b88)`.
If it is not existed, then `(emp123,b88)` will be inserted into the table.

How can I do this with 1 SQL command?

Comment: Look a this : https://www.sqlite.org/lang_replace.html

Comment: Does `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` solves your problem?

Comment: `... OR REPLACE` just deletes any old row before inserting the new one. But why do you want to do this with only one SQL statement?

Comment: @rbr94: I tried `INSERT INTO employer VALUES ('emp123', 'b88') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE building = 'b88'` but this command has error.

Comment: @CL.: I am learning SQL and I thought that we can do this somehow with only 1 command. :)

Comment: @amateur  You probably forgot `(empid,building)` behind the table name

Comment: @rbr94 That is not valid in SQLite.